# How to use Django-tagging on Openshift

Tags: django, tagging, openshift

I have added the tagging in my app:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='YourAppName',
    version='1.0',
    description='OpenShift App',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='example@example.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    install_requires=['Django>=1.3','MySQL-python','tagging',],
)
```

After `git push`, an error shows that:

```
ImportError: cannot import name parse_lookup
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks for your help at first!

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue.  The problem is that parse_lookup was removed.  "parse_lookup is gone due to the queryset-refactor and for good reasons. For the record, django-tagging problems should *not* be reported here and it has been fixed in its trunk version."  -https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7680

Try going here: http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/
and install off the svn trunk:

```
svn checkout http://django-tagging.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tagging-trunk
```

Add the tagging folder in there to your libs folder.  Then add it to your PYTHONPATH - on openshift you need something like this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'libs', 'tagging'))
```

To your wsgi/application